# wp_insert_post does not write my post_name

Tags: wp-insert-post

i tried to generate a page via wp_insert_post. That works fine except that the post_name is always written with the same value as the post_title.
Here comes the code snippet:

```
// Create homesite if not exists

$ins_home = array(
    'post_title' => 'Home',
    'post_name' => 'my-home-site',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed'
);

$result = $wpdb->query("SELECT wpost.post_name FROM $wpdb->posts wpost WHERE wpost.post_name = 'my-home-site'");

if($result < 1){// Insert the post into the database
    $page_id = wp_insert_post( $ins_home );
}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Joe

Comment: I just tried the original code and it works. I don't think it's the code that wrong. Something else may be messing with code.

Answer (score 1):

Gr8 job... only thing missing is the action and the timing for it to work...

try this:

```
$ins_home = array(
    'post_title'    =>  'Home',
    'post_name'     =>  'my-home-site',
    'post_status'   => array('publish'),
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed'
);

$ins_home_id = wp_insert_post($ins_home, 10, 1);

$result = $wpdb->query("SELECT wpost.post_name FROM $wpdb->posts wpost WHERE wpost.post_name = 'my-home-site'");

if($result < 1){// Insert the post into the database
    do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post', 10, 1); 
}
```

.

**EDIT**
According to the Source code of wp_insert_post

```
if ( empty($data['post_name']) && !in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
    $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title'], $post_ID);
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_name' => $data['post_name'] ), $where );
}
```

So... if post_status not in array... post_name = post_title (sanitized ofCourse)
So... altough i am very short on time to check it today you should try to envelope
the 'publish' post_status with an aray - see my revised code

.

i hope this solves it... please try it and share results

Comment: Sagive SEO, thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your code. But still the same result. The post_name has the same value as the post_title. (just in lowercases).

Comment: i had a look in the source code of wp_insert_post and revised my answer - hope this works... got to run to my job - would check back later