# post_name empty after wp_insert_post

Tags: posts, query-posts

I'm writing an external tool that inserts post in wordpress (I'm using the wordpress functions).
I read also this discussion: [wp_insert_post does not write my post_name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62324/wp-insert-post-does-not-write-my-post-name)

But my problem is a little different. I do the insert of post, but post_name is empty.
The code is:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => $article_title,
'post_name'   => $article_title,
'post_content'  => $article_content,
'post_status'   => 'pending',
'post_author'   => 1,
'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

I tried with and without the post_name, but the result did not change. I also tried after:

```
$post_ID = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;
$post_name = wp_unique_post_slug($article_title, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent);
$where = array( 'ID' => $post_ID );
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_name' => $post_name ), $where );
```

But so for example, insert the post_name but:

1. isn't unique
2. not sanitize, for example "Test" doesn't became "test"

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use `post_category`, because according to the wordpress codex [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post):

> 'post_category'  => [ array(, <...>) ] //post_category no longer exists, try wp_set_post_terms() for setting a post's categories

Secondly, if you want the post title to be your slug you shouldn't need to use the `post_name` parameter, because it gets constructed from the title by default. It'd be advisable to make sure your title is tag free, changing the according line to:

```
'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $article_title ),
```

If you really want to add the parameter `post_name` manually make sure to [sanitize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Slugs) and assure [uniqueness](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug):

```
'post_name'   => wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $article_title ) ),
```

Aside from above points your code looks correct to me. The only other thing in mind about not getting a post name would be related to the value `pending` for the parameter `post_status` you have chosen, take a look at the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2901) yourself. What that means - if I'm not totally mistaken - is, that if the post status changes to a publishing state - publish or private for example - a update is performed and then the post name gets inserted to the database. Before - with post statuses auto-draft, draft or pending - that's not happening.

Comment: Using `'post_name'   => wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $post->post_title ) ), ` generates the error `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_unique_post_slug()`

Comment: @Motivated you're quite right; that answer is from 2013; nowadays, `wp_unique_post_slug()` takes at least five arguments, e.g. `'post_name'   => wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $article_title ), $id, 'pending', 'post', 0 )`